# How do I tell Hibernate Search to index FetchType.LAZY fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have a simple model that looks like this (using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations):

```
@Data
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Game {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES)
  public String name;

  @Column(name="description", columnDefinition="TEXT")
  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES)
  public String description;  
}
```

To index this I have written a simple generic indexer that looks like this (this indexes multiple classes hence the lack of a concrete type):

```
  private int index(Class<?> object, FullTextSession search_session) {
    ScrollableResults results = search_session.createCriteria(object)
                                              .setFetchSize(100)
                                              .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    int index = 0;
    while(results.next()) {
      index++;
      search_session.index(results.get(0));
      if (index % 10 == 0) {
        search_session.flushToIndexes();
        search_session.clear();
      }
    }
    search_session.flushToIndexes();
    search_session.clear();
    return index;
  }
```

To invoke this I simple call it like this:

```
FullTextSession search_session = Search.getFullTextSession(dao);
search_session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
search_session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

index(Game.class, search_session);
```

However while the `name` field works as expected, the `description` never gets populated and thus never gets indexed.  If I remove the `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` annotation from `description` then the code works as expected.  To work around this I have updated my index function to take a concrete type and now I manually call `.getDescription()` but is there a cleaner way to accomplish this? Some way to tell Hibernate to fully populate lazy fields on `.get()`?

In response to [karim mohsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32045686/16959) I have modified my `index()` function to look like this (the key difference is that I am calling `Hibernate.initialize()`):

```
private <T> int index(Class<T> object, FullTextSession search_session) {
  ScrollableResults results = search_session.createCriteria(object)
                                            .setFetchSize(100)
                                              .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
  int index = 0;
  while(results.next()) {
    index++;
    T item = (T)results.get(0);
    Hibernate.initialize(item);
    search_session.index(item);
    if (index % 10 == 0) {
      search_session.flushToIndexes();
      search_session.clear();
    }
  }
  search_session.flushToIndexes();
  search_session.clear();
  return index;
}
```

However this approach is still not indexing the `description` field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy-loading a collection normally, but for a particular use, you need to ensure the collection has been loaded before the session is closed, you can use `Hibernate.initialize(Object obj)`

If you in fact always need the collection loaded, you should indeed load it eagerly

Comment: I tried to implement your answer however it is still not indexing the 'description' field.  Could `Hibernate.initialize` only work on collections?

Comment: it is used to Force initialization of a proxy or persistent collection this only ensures initialization of a proxy object or collection; it is not guaranteed that the elements INSIDE the collection will be initialized/materialized. See [this](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch02s02.html) link

Comment: Unfortunately the link suggests that the best approach in this case is to explicitly fetch the lazy property. I'm beginning to give up hope that there is some generic function that will enumerate all fields before indexing.